# CSS absolute position, z-index

Tags: css

This must be really simple but I'm stuck.

I have a header and below I have a full height/width block that is absolutely positioned. This will be a map but I have just used a coloured block to make it simple.

On top of this background I need the page that is 100% height in the middle. I thought I could use the z-index to show this on top of the absolutely positioned background but the page is always behind the 'bg' div

I know I'm missing something simple

```css
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html, body{
  height: 100%;
}

.header{
  background: black;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
}

.bg{
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.page{
  background: grey;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 500px;
  z-index: 10;
}
```

```html
<div class="header"></div>

<div class="bg"></div>

<div class="page"></div>
```

Comment: off-topic, but consider using `<header>` and `<main>` elements instead of divs with classes :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`z-index`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index) has no effect on statically-positioned elements (which is the default). It affects relative, absolute and fixed ("positioned") elements. A common hack would be to add `position:relative` to your `.page`.

Answer (score 3):

To force an absolute positioned element for indexing you could use it in negative.

```css
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html, body{
  height: 100%;
}

.header{
  background: black;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
}

.bg{
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}

.page{
  background: grey;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 500px;
  z-index: 10;
}
```

```html
<div class="header"></div>

<div class="bg"></div>

<div class="page"></div>
```

Comment: just add a reason before you do that

Comment: the reason is that z-index is relative to the z-index of other positioned elements, and the `.page` is not positioned so its z-index is ignored, as I have explained in my answer.

Comment: OK, I'll remove the downvote because negative z-indexes actually work (versus statically-positioned elements which are always on z-index zero) but this needs some explanation, and removing the misleading z-index from the `.page`